# Why argue over whether people want their wheat wet?

Tags: machlokes, maseches-machshirin

Stuff becomes *muchshar l'kabel tum'a*, contaminable, if it becomes wet by the owner's will (or at least by human will).

*Machshirin*, chapter 3, *mishna* 5, in my own, loose translation:

> Suppose someone's transporting wheat to be ground, and rain fell on it. If he was glad, it's *muchshar*. Rabbi *Y'huda* says: No way he's not glad! Rather, if he stood still [so the wheat would get wet], it's *muchshar*.

The commentaries explain that he wants the wheat to get wet because you have to wet it before you grind it. (And that Rabbi *Y'huda* holds that an action is necessary to demonstrate his will.)

So, besides the difference of opinion as to whether an action is necessary to demonstrate one's will, there's also a difference of opinion as to whether everyone wants his wheat wet before grinding it? Seems like a strange argument to have. Go get Richard Dawson to ask a hundred farmers and see what they say. How do we understand this?

Comment: Perhaps the machlokes is the level of happiness that’s required. The Tana Kama holds that it needs to be a positive Simcha (maybe speaking it out) not just a passive happiness. While R Yehuda holds that of happiness is enough then any happiness will do. Rather he requires an action to show his intention

Comment: @Chatzkel The Tosafos Yom Tov to Mishna 7 there quotes the Maharam as basically saying that.

Comment: If the majority is glad from this, maybe Chazal would decree that we assume it is muchshar